# How can I start this JQuery validation when the form is submitted clicking on a submit input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, struts2-jquery

I am absolutly new in JQuery and I have the following problem. Into a page I have a form, something like this:

```
<s:form id="projectForm">
     <s:textfield name="kmProjectInfo.name" size="19"/>
     .....................................
     .....................................
     .....................................
     <s:submit style="display:none" id="submitButton" action="projectCreationAction"/>
</s:form>
```

The  tag is a tag from the Struts 2 UI tag library that simple render a form and the  render the following standard HTML **input** tag into my page:

```
<input type="text" id="kmProjectInfo_name" value="" size="19" name="kmProjectInfo.name">
```

And the  tag render this standard HTML **submit input button** into my page:

```
<input id="submitButton" type="submit" style="" value="Submit" name="action:projectCreationAction">
```

Then in my page I definied this JQuery **validation script**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // VALIDATION:
    var validator = $("#projectForm").validate({
        rules: {
            "kmProjectInfo.name": "required"
        },
        messages: {
            "kmProjectInfo.name": "Please enter a project name"
        }
    })
});
```

As you can see this script simpl take the previous rendered input field having **name="kmProjectInfo.name"** and say that thif field is requiered.

My problem is that currently the script start when the document is completly loaded (because it is definied into **$(document).ready() function**) but I absolutly need that the validation happens only when the form is submitted clicking on the rendered input field having **id="submitButton"**, this one:

```
<input id="submitButton" type="submit" style="" value="Submit" name="action:projectCreationAction">
```

How can I do this thing? Can you help me to do it?

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#projectForm").on('submit',function(){
     // VALIDATION:
     var validator = $(this).validate({
         rules: {
            "kmProjectInfo.name": "required"
         },
         messages: {
            "kmProjectInfo.name": "Please enter a project name"
         }
     });
   });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Put your code in onclick of submitButton

```
$("#submitButton").on('click',function() {

        // VALIDATION:

        var validator = $("#projectForm").validate({
            rules: {
                "kmProjectInfo.name": "required"
            },
            messages: {
                "kmProjectInfo.name": "Please enter a project name"
            }
        })
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).on("click","#submitButton",function(e)
{
    // VALIDATION:
    var validator = $("#projectForm").validate({
        rules: {
            "kmProjectInfo.name": "required"
        },
        messages: {
            "kmProjectInfo.name": "Please enter a project name"
        }
    })
});
```

or if you want to keep it in the document ready body:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{      
    $("#submitButton").click(function(){
        // VALIDATION:
        var validator = $("#projectForm").validate({
            rules: {
                "kmProjectInfo.name": "required"
            },
            messages: {
                "kmProjectInfo.name": "Please enter a project name"
            }
        })
    });  
});
```